# Building hudson view present on the slave machine

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

Is it possible to build project present on the developer view present on different machine, not on the Hudson running machine?
If so please provide me way.

-Srinivas N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need the notion of Hudson **node** to do that.
A Node is detailed in the Hudson page "[**Distributed build**](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds)"

> Hudson supports the "**master/slave**" mode, where the workload of building projects are delegated to multiple "slave" nodes, allowing single Hudson installation to host a large number of projects, or provide different environments needed for builds/tests

That will allow you to build while accessing the developer view on the developer's workstation (since all the execution process will take place on the developer's machine).

Comment: Do we have any step by step guide on this?

Comment: @srinannapa: your slave is a Windows or Unix one?

Comment: @srinannapa: for Windows slave,see http://pip.openplans.org/ci-server-step-by-step.html for instance.

Comment: @srinannapa: for Unix, use SSH or another method like http://java.dzone.com/articles/starting-hudson-slave-unix?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+javalobby%2Ffrontpage+%28Javalobby+%2F+Java+Zone%29